# Unable to run ASP.NET Core rc2 in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, asp.net-core

So, I've been trying to publish my Core App to local IIS server but whatever I do it just doesn't want to run.

What I do is find the project in windows explorer and open a command window there, and write the following:

```
dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp1.0 --output "C:/ReleaseWebsite" --configuration Release
```

Which well executes without any errors, and finally says that it published the project correctly.

After that I go to IIS and Add New Website, set it to port 80 or 8080, I even tried with 8088, and after set the path to the published files, I edit the Application Pool and set it to No Managed Code. Start the website but all I get it 500 error An error occurred while starting the application.

If I go manually to the published files and open GST.Web.exe it starts without any issues, and rusn on port 5000 and I can access it without any problems. But I want to run it in IIS. Any help?

Comment: If you get `startup` errors you can enable extra startup options to output the actual reason. Have a look at my blog post about it. http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/asp-net-core-how-to-fix-error-occurred.html

Answer (score 2):

Refer [Publishing to IIS](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) article.

I think you must have done all the steps from this article except installing .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle on the server.

Install the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827547) on the server.

This bundle will install the .NET Core Runtime, .NET Core Library, and the ASP.NET Core Module. The module creates the reverse-proxy between IIS and the Kestrel server.

See if this helps.

Comment: I have installed that, I just forgot to mention sorry.

Comment: Can you please attached complete screenshot of error?

Comment: Verify your ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable and corresponding AppSettings.json. Verify you are able to connect to all connections etc

Comment: I was able to setup project to display detailed errors. 
Here is what I have now [screen](http://i.imgur.com/tHwINpa.png)

project.json was missing, but even after I added it to the directory, it still throws the same exception.

Comment: Edit, fixed the upper error message. Here is new: [image](http://i.imgur.com/KuZtNdF.png)

Comment: Its database permission error.., from here on, i think you know what needs to be done :)